# Existence of only one extension

Tags: extension-field, galois-extensions

Ok so i have the spliting field of $f(x)=x^{p}-3$, say it's $F$, and i know $[F:\mathbb Q]= p(p-1)$
I have to show there exists only one extension $L$ such $[F:L]=p-1$, that there is one It comes directly from the spliting field, but How one can prove it's the only one?

Comment: Can you work out the Galois group?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown i actually didn't found it, i tought i could solve without expliciting It, but $F= \mathbb Q (3^{1/p})(e^{\frac {2πi}{p}})$ thus the degree is $p(p-1)$

Comment: I do have the general case Galois group for an $g(x)=x^p -q$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: show that the Galois group of $F$ has a unique subgroup of order $p-1$ (it is a semi-direct product of two cyclic groups) and apply the fundamental theorem of the Galois theory.